# Can a singularity really exist?

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon, singularities

Okay, so I have an idea and I wanted to know if it works out or not.

I imagine a black hole to form from a star, which is rotating. Let's say the star collapses because of some reason, and a black hole forms. While it is collapsing, it is spinning faster and faster (just like a dancer when they move their arms closer).

Is it possible for that black hole to fall into a single point? Wouldn't the spinning speed be infinite? I would imagine that at some point while the star is collapsing, the centripetal force takes over and the black hole does not become a singularity, but rather a "ringularity".

Could my theory be correct or is there a big flaw in it? I'd love to read more.

Comment: You are right.. rotating stars form rotating black holes which have a ringularity.

Comment: @PNS Does that mean that all black holes are ringularities?

Comment: See [Ring Singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_singularity) or google rotating black hole singularity

Comment: @user1009013 practically yes, because stars we observe always have some rotation. Theoretically, you can construct black holes from stationary stars.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_singularity and the cited papers at the bottom, if you want to read papers. In particular, read the papers cited in the intros to get a reading list of influential papers in the subject.

Comment: P.S., the accepted name for it still is "singularity" even though it's more than just one single point.